# comparing columns within groupby objects in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
id      month       spent       limit
1        1           2.6         10
1        2           4           10
1        3           6           10
2        1           3           100
2        2           89          100
2        3           101         100
3        1           239         500
3        2           432         500
3        3           100         500
```

I want to groupby id and then get the ids for which spent column is less than or equal to limit column for every row in the grouped by object.

For my above example, I should get ids 1 and 3 as my result because id 2 spends 101 in 3rd month and hence exceeds the limit of 100.

How can I do this in pandas efficiently?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mask by finding the ids where spent is **greater than limit**. The mask out the ids in the mask

```
mask = df.loc[df['spent'] > df['limit'], 'id'].values.tolist()
df.id[df['id'] != mask].unique()
```

gives you

```
array([1, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you something like what you want

```
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda g: (g.spent < g.limit).all()).to_frame('not_exceeded').query('not_exceeded == True')
```

Answer (score 1):

Reverse logic!  Check for unique ids where spent is greater than limit.  Then filter out those.

```
df[~df.id.isin(df.set_index('id').query('limit < spent').index.unique())]

   id  month  spent  limit
0   1      1    2.6     10
1   1      2    4.0     10
2   1      3    6.0     10
6   3      1  239.0    500
7   3      2  432.0    500
8   3      3  100.0    500
```